# Small perturbation of linear transformation cannot decrease its rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ has rank $k$.Show that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if for a linear transformation $S:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ we have that $\left \|S-T  \right \|<\delta$, then $rank(S)\geqslant k$.

My hunch tells me that the proof should be simple, but a cannot figure this out. I'd appreciate a small hint.

Comment: I was about to say this is false. You got the title wrong: A small perturbation _can_ increase the rank - it cannot _decrease_ the rank.

Comment: Yes, thank for spotting it. Corrected it.

Comment: You can put $T$ in canonical form (reduced row echelon or whatever it is called) and show the result in that case. It should work I guess.

Comment: The rank of a matrix can expressed by certain under-deteminants. Use than that deteminants are continuous functions.

Comment: @sigmabe Could you be more specific? I mean, could you give more details on how to express ranks in term of those "under-determinants"? I'm  not sure what you mean by that. 
The continuity of the determinant looks like a good hint. As the formulation of the problems is a bit like an $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity .

Comment: I've written my idea as answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rank of a linear transformation can be expressed by [Minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29). The rank is $\geq k$ if and only if there is a non zero $k\times k$-minor. Because the determinant is a continous function, we get that all transformation in a neighbourhood have also a non zero $k\times k$-minor and therefore rank $\geq k$.

Comment: Nice! In other words, due to that "if and only if" part we can switch from rank to the analysis of minors; even better, to the determinant function.

Comment: @Tomas rank $k$ means that there are $k$ vectors in $T$ whose image spans $k$-dimensional space in $S$. A small pertubation to this image cannot collapse the span to a lower dimensional space because linear functions are continuous. Minors/determinants capture this but aren't necessary.